# C++ - Removing invalid characters when a user paste in a grid

Tags: c++builder

Here's my situation.  I have an issue where I need to filter invalid characters that a user may paste from word or excel documents.

Here is what I'm doing.

First I'm trying to convert any unicode characters to ascii

```
extern "C" COMMON_STRING_FUNCTIONS long ConvertUnicodeToAscii(wchar_t * pwcUnicodeString, char* &pszAsciiString)
{
    int nBufLen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pwcUnicodeString, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)+1;
    pszAsciiString = new char[nBufLen];
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pwcUnicodeString, -1, pszAsciiString, nBufLen, NULL, NULL);
    return nBufLen;
}
```

Next I'm filtering out any character that does not have a value between 31 and 127

```
String __fastcall TMainForm::filterInput(String l_sConversion)
{
    // Used to store every character that was stripped out.
    String filterChars = "";

    // Not Used.  We never received the whitelist
    String l_SWhiteList = "";

    // Our String without the invalid characters.
    AnsiString l_stempString;

    // convert the string into an array of chars
    wchar_t* outputChars = l_sConversion.w_str();
    char * pszOutputString = NULL;

    //convert any unicode characters to ASCII
    ConvertUnicodeToAscii(outputChars, pszOutputString);

    l_stempString = (AnsiString)pszOutputString;

    //We're going backwards since we are removing characters which changes the length and position.
    for (int i = l_stempString.Length(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        char l_sCurrentChar = l_stempString[i];

        //If we don't have a valid character, filter it out of the string.
        if (((unsigned int)l_sCurrentChar < 31) ||((unsigned int)l_sCurrentChar > 127))
        {
            String l_sSecondHalf = "";
            String l_sFirstHalf = "";
            l_sSecondHalf = l_stempString.SubString(i + 1, l_stempString.Length() - i);
            l_sFirstHalf = l_stempString.SubString(0, i - 1);
            l_stempString = l_sFirstHalf + l_sSecondHalf;
            filterChars += "\'" + ((String)(unsigned int)(l_sCurrentChar)) + "\' ";
        }
    }

    if (filterChars.Length() > 0)
    {
        LogInformation(__LINE__, __FUNC__, Utilities::LOG_CATEGORY_GENERAL, "The Following ASCII Values were filtered from the string: " + filterChars);
    }

    // Delete the char* to avoid memory leaks.
    delete [] pszOutputString;
    return l_stempString;
}
```

Now this seems to work except, when you try to copy and past bullets from a word document.

> o Bullet1:
>    subbullet1.

You will get something like this

> oBullet1?subbullet1.

My filter function is called on an onchange event.

The bullets are replaced with the value o and a question mark.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way of trying to do this.

I'm using c++ builder XE5 so please no Visual C++ solutions.

Comment: `CP_ACP` does not represent ASCII, it represents the OS's current locale, which could be any language.  ASCII itself is codepage 20127 instead. It is also redundant to define your own conversion function when you can just use `AnsiStringT<20127>` instead and let the RTL handle the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the conversion to ASCII (which is *not* actually converting to ASCII, btw), Unicode characters that are not supported by the target codepage are lost - either dropped, replaced with `?`, or replaced with a close approximation - so they are not available to your scanning loop. You should not do the conversion at all, scan the source Unicode data as-is instead.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <System.Character.hpp>

String __fastcall TMainForm::filterInput(String l_sConversion)
{
    // Used to store every character sequence that was stripped out.
    String filterChars;

    // Not Used.  We never received the whitelist
    String l_SWhiteList;

    // Our String without the invalid sequences.
    String l_stempString;

    int numChars;
    for (int i = 1; i <= l_sConversion.Length(); i += numChars)
    {
        UCS4Char ch = TCharacter::ConvertToUtf32(l_sConversion, i, numChars);
        String seq = l_sConversion.SubString(i, numChars);

        //If we don't have a valid codepoint, filter it out of the string.
        if ((ch <= 31) || (ch >= 127))
            filterChars += (_D("\'") + seq + _D("\' "));
        else
            l_stempString += seq;
    }

    if (!filterChars.IsEmpty())
    {
        LogInformation(__LINE__, __FUNC__, Utilities::LOG_CATEGORY_GENERAL, _D("The Following Values were filtered from the string: ") + filterChars);
    }

    return l_stempString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It looks like what you wrote is stripping out most bullets however clear bullets are still being converted to 'o'.  Is this just windows copy/paste behavior.

Comment: This code should be stripping out all bullets, since there are no bullets in ASCII.